# Is there any control or in way to use DateTime slider in windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, slider, trackbar

I have a winForm, in which have a requirement to use Silder that could slide on `DateTime` and grid is refreshed according to the date selected.

Is there any control that provides above functionality.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A trackbar to select a time is somewhat conceivable.  But for *date*, no.  Use a DateTimePicker.

Comment: @HansPassant actually trackbar is very good for selecting dates, especially for date ranges. http://demos.devexpress.com/aspxeditorsdemos/ASPxTrackBar/Items.aspx

Comment: @lazy, that selects a day, not a date.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this control has name [`TrackBar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.trackbar.aspx). You can use it without labels:

```
DateTime beginDate = //
DateTime endDate = //
datesTrackBar.Maximum = (int)(endDate - beginDate).TotalDays;
```

And filter your grid on `Scroll` event:

```
private void datesTrackBar_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime selectedDate = beginDate.AddDays(datesTrackBar.Value);
    // filter grid
}
```

Or you can create your own `TimeSlider` control via inheriting from `TrackBar` and overriding it's `OnPaint` event.

Here you can see an example of [creating custom slider](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13712/TimeSlider-A-time-based-TrackBar).