# NET DateTimePicker SelectionStart and SelectionLength properties

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm trying to get like SelectionStart and SelectionLength properties for DateTimePicker but without success.
Since those properties is not present I try to get TextBoxBase inside of DTP through subclassing. Also without any usable results. Like this:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnKeyDown(e As KeyEventArgs)

    Dim txtBase As TextBoxBase = TryCast(Me.Controls(0), TextBoxBase)
    _selectionStart = txtBase.SelectionStart
    _selectionLength = txtBase.SelectionLength
...
```

Any idea how to get TextBoxBase or SelectionStart and SelectionLength of DTP for use in VB.NET or C#?

Comment: Can you describe what you are trying to do?  The Value for a DTP is a DateTime, so whatever they select internally is going to be part of a date such as `dtp.Value.Month`

Comment: Well, selection is not and would not be part of a date/time. I woul need to know when days is selected so I can handle Escape key differently. Yes, sadly, DTP is a real Frankenstein control.

Comment: You would have to create your own control. Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13112915/2882256) is a start. Or just go easy and have two DateTimePickers: 1. From 2. Until.

Comment: There are so many lacks in DTP that writing my own control would be good idea. But not for now, haven't time for this at the moment. I still belive that it is somehow possible to reach internal textbox of DTP and his properties.

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you describe what you mean by "Selection"? `DateTimePicker` is a control for picking a single `DateTime`. What is the "Selection" that can have a start and a length, and why do you think it already exists somewhere inside `DateTimePicker`?